# div inside table td in the right upper corner?

Tags: javascript, html, css

code inside the `<td>` (from inspect element):

```
<td colspan="6" class="google-visualization-orgchart-node google-visualization-orgchart-node-medium google-visualization-orgchart-nodesel">
<div class="col-md-8">Rian Priyanto </div>
<div class="col-md-1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
<div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></div>
</td>
```

real code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  google.charts.load('current', {packages:["orgchart"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Parent');

    data.addRows([
      <?php
        foreach ($query as $row) {
           if($row->kode_group >= 1000){$row->kode_group = '';}
           echo '[{v:\''.$row->kode_groups.'\',f:\'<div style="position: relative;width:100%;height:100%;"><div class="col-md-8">'.$row->name.' </div><div class="col-md-1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div><div class="col-md-3" style="position: absolute !important;top: 0;right: 0px;"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></div></div>\'},\''.$row->kode_group.'\'],';
        }
      ?>
    ]);

    // Create the chart.
    var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    // Draw the chart, setting the allowHtml option to true for the tooltips.
    chart.draw(data, {allowHtml:true});
  }
</script>
```

SS:

[image: SS]

In `1`, when the text wrapped, the `<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>` is in the right upper side of `<td>`, but in `2` when the text is only 1 line, it's in the middle.

How to make the `<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>` appear in the right upper corner regardless of the content?

Note:

- The `<td>` is generated by google orgchart javascript, so I don't really know where the code is (I don't understand the js).
- I probably can only edit the content inside the `<td>` not the `<td>` itself (so probably can't add another `<td>` but editing `css` is still okay).
- You can arrange the div freely. All I want is the `text` to be `align: left` + `v. align: middle` & the `icon` to be `align: right` + `v. align: top`
- In case you want to see the page, here is the [save page](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzxeBLxTvFKBdDZyN1FJcTBXYVE)

Answer (score 1):

Apply position style of td as relative and div position style as absolute with top right 0. It will be always on top right corner.

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div style="position: relative;width:100%;height:100%;">
          <div class="col-md-8">
            Rian Priyanto
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-1">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3" style=
          "position: absolute !important;top: 0;right: 0px;">
            <a href="#">+<i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: somehow this doesn't do `regardless of the content`, http://i.stack.imgur.com/gwm7A.png

Comment: If you can not edit td then add parent div like above.

Comment: Remove class(col-md-3) from last div and try

Answer (score 0):

try this way Add `valign top` in td & add class `col-md-3` to `text-right`

```
<td colspan="6" valign="top" class="google-visualization-orgchart-node google-visualization-orgchart-node-medium google-visualization-orgchart-nodesel">
<div class="col-md-8">Rian Priyanto </div>
<div class="col-md-1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
<div class="col-md-3 text-right"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></div>
</td>
```

Comment: I can't edit the `td`, I can only edit what is in `td`, ex: `<td>{my edit range}</td>`

Comment: add css like table tr td {vertical-align:top;}

Comment: `td{vertical-align:top;}` will also make the text in the top, I want the text in the middle but the icon in the top